# How do you use map(reverse, ITERABLE) with arguments to reverse?

Tags: python, django, performance

It is possible to call reverse with arguments for example:

```
reverse('page', args=['page1'])
```

finds the url named page that takes an argument.

My question is how would I do this if I am using Python's map?  I want something of this form:

```
map(reverse, ITERABLE)
```

where iterable is a bunch of of named urls with args.  Thus far I have been unsuccessful at doing this.

**edit based on comments and Adam's and rulfzid's answers:**

The following iterable is an example that works with both rulfzid's (editing it as my comment suggests) and Adam's answer

```
iterable = [['page', ['about']], ['home', None]]
```

My only other question is which would be faster?

Comment: It's not clear what format your iterable is in, nor what you expect done with it. It sounds like you want to use `filter` or a list comprehension instead, to find a specific url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[reverse(page, args=args) for page, args in ITERABLE]
```

Assuming, of course, that ITERABLE is something like `[(page, args), (page1, arg1), ...]`

Comment: I think you mean `[reverse(page, args=[arg]) for arg in ITERABLE]`

Comment: To get it to work for me I modified reverse(page, args) to reverse(page, args=args).

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it works and from what I have read list comprehensions are faster than map() with a lambda function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each item in `ITERABLE` is a tuple (or list) consisting of the URL and the arguments, you could use a lambda like so:

```
map(lambda x: reverse(x[0], args=x[1]), ITERABLE)
```

Comment: do you know how this method would compare in speed to rulfzid's?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
from functools import partial
reverse_page = partial(reverse, 'page', None)
map(reverse_page, ITERABLE)
```

Should do the trick if you need to map:

```
['page1', 'page2', 'page3']
```

with no `url_conf` and `page` as the view.

You can use keyword args with it, but there is no reason to construct `dict`s if you don't need to.

It's faster than using `lambda` or a list comprehension for non-trivial lengths of `iterable` because `reverse` and `'page'` only have to be looked up once.

Edit: If you're not actually using one argument over and over again, `partial` isn't what you want, just plain `map`:

```
map(reverse, ('page', 'home'), itertools.repeat(None), ('about', None))
```

or like this:

```
map(reverse, *zip(('page', None, 'about'), ('home', None, None)))
```

depending on how the info was organized. No need for a lambda here, lambda is slow.

Comment: How would I do this if I wasn't always reversing page, but possibly home or something else?

Comment: Edited -- `partial` doesn't work if you want to vary a positional argument but use the same keyword argument (urlconf), so you need to use `repeat`. I wrote it out above but really you'd want to `from itertools import repeat` instead of `import itertools` then `itertools.repeat` to save the attribute lookup every time.